# Flutter Web - PictureRecorder Image Not Rendering Under a Specific Circumstance

Tags: javascript, flutter, canvas, flutter-web, dart-html

Using a `PictureRecorder` to  generate a `dart:ui Image` which is then rendered on `Canvas`.

The code works as expected when web app is run on Chrome and Firefox by running app as follows from Ubuntu Linux dev desktop:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
flutter run --web-renderer canvaskit --release
```

However, the final release web app is later built on a Raspberry pi 4 to run within a k8s pod on Raspberry pi 4 k8s cluster where the web app gets built as follows:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
```

When the final release web app is then loaded up on the same two Firefox and Chrome web browsers, the web app's `PictureRecorder` `dart:ui Image` renders okay on Firefox but it does NOT render at all on Chrome.

Only difference I can think off in deployed release is the architecture where the final release was built (which is a Raspberry pi 4 - aarch64) compared to dev desktop (which is x86_64).

The web app code runs fully on Web browser client and does not rely on any server-side code once the .js data and assets have all been fetched.

The `PictureRecorder` related code is:

```
const src = Rect.fromLTWH(60, 0, 30, 30);
const dst0 = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 30, 30);
const dst1 = Rect.fromLTWH(30, 0, 30, 30);
const dst2 = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 30, 30, 30);
const dst3 = Rect.fromLTWH(30, 30, 30, 30);

final recorder = PictureRecorder();
final canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    
canvas
  ..save()
  ..drawImageRect(image, src, dst0, spritePaint)
  ..drawImageRect(image, src, dst1, spritePaint)
  ..drawImageRect(image, src, dst2, spritePaint)
  ..drawImageRect(image, src, dst3, spritePaint)
  ..restore();
    
ui.Image recorderImage = await recorder
  .endRecording().toImage(60, 60);

...

/// Image then rendered on a canvas as follows:
canvas.drawImage(recorderImage, Offset.zero, ui.Paint()
    ..color = whColour
    ..filterQuality = ui.FilterQuality.high);
```

Flutter version `stable 3.3.8`.

Answer (score 0):

After coming across this [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103803) post and reading its comments I have built and deployed the web app on the Raspberry Pi 4 using `flutter master` channel (v3.6.x) and with this version, the `PictureRecorder` generated `Image` renders as one would expect in both Firefox and Chrome web browsers.